# "Timeout on blocking read" when using new Spring 6 HTTP Interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webclient

We recently started testing [the new HTTP Interface that came with Spring 6.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#rest-http-interface)

We defined a client like this:

```
    HttpClient client = (HttpClient)((HttpClient)HttpClient.create().option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 5000)).doOnConnected((conn) -> {
        conn.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(10000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
    });
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(client)).baseUrl(locationUrl.toExternalForm()).build();
    HttpServiceProxyFactory factory = HttpServiceProxyFactory.builder(WebClientAdapter.forClient(webClient)).build();
```

An interface can look something like this:

```
@GetExchange("/availability")
    AvailabilityResponse getAvailability(@RequestParam("products") List<String> itemIds);
```

When using the client, we are occasionally getting exceptions like below. We initially thought that this was related to the connect timeout that we defined as 5 seconds, but this seems to be related to the reactor blockingGet rather than the actual HTTP call.

When searching for similar issues, everything I found seem to be related to unit testing of WebClient, with solutions like setting `@AutoConfigureWebTestClient(timeout = "30000")`, so this does not help us.
How can we increase the blocking get timeout to match our ReadTimeoutHandler of 10 seconds?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timeout on blocking read for 5000000000 NANOSECONDS
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:123)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1734)
    at org.springframework.web.service.invoker.HttpServiceMethod$ResponseFunction.execute(HttpServiceMethod.java:296)
    at org.springframework.web.service.invoker.HttpServiceMethod.invoke(HttpServiceMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.service.invoker.HttpServiceProxyFactory$HttpServiceMethodInterceptor.invoke(HttpServiceProxyFactory.java:271)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218)
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy135.searchPharmacies(Unknown Source)
    at <redacted>
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor128.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I went through the same, and used `CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS` and `ReadTimeoutHandler` but still faced time outs after 5 seconds outside of my tests.

I just discovered that on the [`HttpServiceProxyFactory.builder()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.0.0/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/service/invoker/HttpServiceProxyFactory.Builder.html) there is a [`blockTimeout`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.0.0/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/service/invoker/HttpServiceProxyFactory.Builder.html#blockTimeout(java.time.Duration)) that you can configure that defaults to 5 seconds that should resolve your issue.